# Most Recent Date in many-to-many Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query Parts that have not moved in my system for more than 90 days. I am starting to run into a many-to-many issue, and I am very new to SQL.

It needs to work like:

- Look for all PartNos where OrderStatus = 'Open'
- Look then to the PO DateEnt, determine if it is >90 days old
- Look then to the TimeTicket, determine if it is >90 days old

Meets all criteria, post result in query.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
DECLARE @90daysago DATETIME


SET @now = GETDATE()
SET @90daysago = DATEADD(day, -90, @now)



SELECT
    o.PartNo,
    o.JobNo,
    o.Status,

    cast(po.DateEnt as DATE) AS DateEnt,


    tt.TicketDate,
    (o.qtyToMake - o.QtyShipped2Stock) AS NumOpen

FROM
    OrderDet AS o

INNER JOIN PODet AS pod
    ON o.PartNo = pod.PartNo

INNER JOIN PO as po
    ON pod.PONum = po.PONum

INNER JOIN TimeTicketDet as tt
    ON o.JobNo = tt.JobNo

WHERE
    o.Status = 'Open' AND
    o.PartNo = '72347' AND
    o.JobNo = '16516-02'


ORDER BY
    po.DateEnt DESC
```

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMPAogamiVv_19JAQHO3GBYsBr9s6PPt-WXGbdrPTqvW-EAU0QjkCI0s-cidT-IuQ?key=ZElDNzFsdmU2XzZPVmh1d01tWWZLcU1WbllDUzN3

The above link shows a piece of the executed query, I am running it on a mock PartNo.

The first columns are PartNo, JobNo respectively.

The two dates are DateEnt, TicketDate respectively.

As you can see, every single change in our system duplicates the data and shows all of the dates. When I add the criteria >@90daysago then it will show a DateEnt from 12-19-2016 which is a closed Order. I know this is incredibly vague, I just do not know how to show only the most recent values for each date for the query. I will be glad to provide any more useful information.

```
Sample Data
+--------+-------+--------+------------+------------+
| PartNo | JobNo | Status |  DateEnt   | TicketDate |
+--------+-------+--------+------------+------------+
|  72347 |     1 | OPEN   | 12/19/2016 | 10/6/2016  |
|  72347 |     2 | OPEN   | 12/19/2016 | 10/5/2016  |
|  72347 |     3 | OPEN   | 12/19/2016 | 12/23/2016 |
|  72347 |     4 | OPEN   | 12/19/2016 | 12/23/2016 |
|  72347 |     1 | OPEN   | 12/19/2016 | 10/6/2016  |
|  72347 |     2 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 10/5/2016  |
|  72347 |     3 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 12/23/2016 |
|  72347 |     4 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 12/23/2016 |
|  72347 |     1 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 10/6/2016  |
|  72347 |   200 | OPEN   | 1/9/2017   | 10/5/2016  |
|  72347 |     3 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 12/23/2016 |
|  72347 |     4 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 12/26/2016 |
|  72347 |     1 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 10/6/2016  |
|  72347 |     2 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 10/5/2016  |
|  72347 |     3 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 12/23/2016 |
|  72347 |     4 | OPEN   | 3/30/2017  | 12/23/2016 |
+--------+-------+--------+------------+------------+

Sample Result
+--------+-------+--------+----------+------------+--+
| PartNo | JobNo | Status | DateEnt  | TicketDate |  |
+--------+-------+--------+----------+------------+--+
|  72347 |   200 | OPEN   | 1/9/2017 | 10/5/2017  |  |
+--------+-------+--------+----------+------------+--+
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: In your query the only link between po/pod and tt is o. So if you have 2 pod for an o and 3 tt for it, you get 6 result rows, because you combine every po/pod with every tt (as there is no criteria to join a tt record to a particular pod record). This is probably not what you want, but what do you want instead? Make up a small example and think about what result you actually want. How many rows in that case? Which columns? What content in the cells?

Comment: Try `row_number()`

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sample data and results have been posted.

Comment: 1. Why only one row? The first five rows meet your criteria as well. Why are they not in the result? 2. This sample data is invalid. You are showing one combined table. But there is no such combined table in your database. There are four separate tables. Please show sample data with the four tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. You can adjust PARTITION BY and ORDER BY to meet your requirement.

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT o.PartNo
   , o.JobNo
   , o.Status
   , CAST(po.DateEnt as DATE) AS DateEnt
   , tt.TicketDate
   , (o.qtyToMake - o.QtyShipped2Stock) AS NumOpen
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.PartNo ORDER BY po.DateEnt DESC, tt.TicketDate DESC) AS Rownum
FROM OrderDet AS o
INNER JOIN PODet AS pod
    ON o.PartNo = pod.PartNo
INNER JOIN PO AS po
    ON pod.PONum = po.PONum
INNER JOIN TimeTicketDet AS tt
    ON o.JobNo = tt.JobNo
WHERE o.Status = 'Open' 
AND po.DateEnt < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()), 120)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Rownum = 1
AND TicketDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()), 120);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This queries the information much more efficiently. However, it is still pulling data from the PO DateEnt from 12/19/2016. It is as if the query goes and finds the first PO DateEnt >90 days old even if is closed. I can add in a r.ReceiveDate to cross reference maybe? It is just the date that claims that the PO order was shipped back and received.

Comment: Sample data and results have been posted.

Comment: Those PartNo with DateEnt of 12-19-2016 are Open status. They are all fit your requirements 'Opent' and more than 90 days. Unless you add more conditions or update the records as closed. They should appear in the output.

Comment: Would it be easier to query first for anything with a MAX(DateEnt) & MAX(TicketDate) >90 days partitioned for PartNo then check to see if its open or closed and post the result?

Comment: Still pulling the 12/19/2016 but just showing 1 JobNo now. I think i am going to rethink the entire approach because I you pointed out ealier, the query is doing its job with the criteria given. Thank you again by the way, I really appreciate you trying to help me.